# Django filter AVG - Rating

Tags: django, django-models

How can I get the average rating??

Model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product ,blank=True, null=True)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    review = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My try..

rating = Review.objects.filter(vendor=vendor).annotate(Avg('rating'))

template:

{{rating.rating__avg}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a single average for a queryset, you need to use `aggregate` rather than `annotate`.

```
rating = Review.objects.filter(vendor=my_vendor).aggregate(Avg('rating'))
```